# Django file upload ajax call post using jquery

Tags: ajax, django, file, upload

How exactly do I upload a file using an ajax call ? 
My form in template

```
<form action="images/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="upload">                                            
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <td><input type = "button" onclick="" value="Upload" id = "test"/</td>
    </table>
</form>
```

My jQuery function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        var string = $("form.upload").serialize();
        alert(string);
        $.ajax({
            url :'/test/',
            type:'post',
            data: {datas:string},  
        dataType: "json",           
         success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                  }
        });
    });
});
```

My view :

```
@csrf_exempt        
def test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Saved !!!!")
```

Here I have the view for the file upload but the file does not appear in the form variable in the django view . What should I do to get the file in the view ?
The form has a filefield for uploading . It is a model form.

Answer (score 4):

2 important pieces are missing here:

1. jQuery.serialize() doesn't do anything to file fields. Check out [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for a robust method of posting form with files via Ajax
2. You need to explicitly pass the uploaded files to the form constructor: `form = ImageUploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)`